# Sum only if not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to put together a formula that sums 3 cells, but if they're blank I don't want to sum them.

If there's no values in the cell, it gives me "0" as a result, but I only want to have a "0" if the cells value are actually "0" and not blank.

As an example i used this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(J6,J7,J8)<3,"",SUM(J6,J7,J8))
```

It's not giving me a result until I fill the 3 values, and I want it to sum it even if I only have 2 values.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition results in the `SUM` not being calculated *unless* you have values in all three cells.

```
=SUM(J6,J7,J8)
```

Will do the job just fine no matter the number of cells filled in. If you really don't want a `0` when none of the cells have a value, use:

```
=IF(COUNTA(C4,E4,G4)=0,"",SUM(C4,E4,G4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK((J8)),ISBLANK(J7),ISBLANK(J8))=TRUE,"",SUM(J6:J8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I've solved the issue using an Array formula with different approach.Where the Formula checks all the possibilities.**

**N.B.** *Check the Caption with each Screen Shot for better understanding.*

[image]

*Finish this Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.*

```
{=IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$3),0, IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK($A$1:$A$3)),"",SUM($A$1:$A$3)))}
```

**Note:**

- First part of the Formula `=IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$3),0,` works for
  all Blank Cells(Situation 5).
- `IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1)` with further combination prevents Excel to return Blank if the First Cell is Blank (Situation 2).